# Npm test failing only on directory name match

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, homebrew, babeljs

Global Env Setup as defined by project maintainer and staff:

1. `node -v`: 8.9.4
2. `npm -v`: 6.10.2
3. Tests build in jest
4. Vue project

**Scenario:**

1. I was attempting to implement `eslint` into a project.
2. `Unexpected token import` errors from `npm test` on all branches; Believed to be a babel error, and did attempt at a `parser: "babel-eslint" option in`.eslintrc`. Furthermore, attempted fix with ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs)
3. Found a way for project to work again:

   ```
   rm -rf proj
   git clone http://proj
   mv proj foo && cd foo
   npm install
   npm test #tests pass
   ```
4. FAILS (with the installation and process as setup in 3):

   ```
   mv foo proj && cd proj
   npm test
   ```

I went as far as removing all installations of `node`, `npm`, and `eslint` (as well as all of my `node_modules` globals and reinstalling to versions mentioned above. I also looked into clearing npm cache. `which npm` and `brew uninstall` as well as `brew doctor` were used in the uninstalling process. I also checked for node and npm per [steps defined in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

**I still cannot let my project live in its correct named directory without continuing to have errors.**

Obvious solution to keep working is to just rename the directory structure, but I am hoping someone has an idea as to WHY this is happening...

Comment: what is the project's actual name?

Comment: @Joe it is proprietary software and the code base is private outside of the company. Sorry to not give it out. Thankfully, I do not think it is relevant to the problem at hand.